# KnockoutJs Computed - 'Is not a function'

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Essentially i've got the following code-snippet in JS :

```
var pgViewModel = { 
    inited : false,
    username : ko.observable("", {persist: "login.username"}),
    password : ko.observable("", {persist: "login.password"}),
    vehicles : ko.observableArray(),    
    selectedVehicle : ko.observable(null, {persist: "login.vehicle"}),
    tirepressure : ko.computed(function(){
        var selecV = this.selectedVehicle();
        return selecV.tirepressure_vl + '/' + selecV.tirepressure_vr + '/'     +          selecV.tirepressure_hl + '/' + slecV.tirepressure_hr + 'bar';
    },this),
```

Whilst trying to load the page i get the error : 'this.selectedVehicle() is not a function'. Occurs this problem because the pgViewModel is not ready when the function is parsed? Is there a possible solution. I'm sorry but i don't understand the problem here in every detail. thanks.

Comment: Please show whole *viewModel*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem you're getting is related to context and `this` value at invocation time. It is highly *recommended to avoid* direct `this` usage in `knockout` view models. Instead create additional [`self`](http://www.javascriptkata.com/2007/05/14/how-to-use-the-self-with-object-oriented-javascript-and-closures/) field which will be initialized on object creation.

```
var self = this;
...
tirepressure : ko.computed(function(){
        var selecV = self.selectedVehicle();
```

Seems like you've messed up something with your `ViewModel` without full code there is no way to find root cause. I've updated it a bit and everything seems working fine:

```
function pgViewModel() {
    var self = this;    
    self.inited = false;
    self.username = ko.observable("", {persist: "login.username"});
    self.password = ko.observable("", {persist: "login.password"});
    self.vehicles = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedVehicle = ko.observable(null, { persist: "login.vehicle"});
    self.tirepressure = ko.computed(function() {
        var selecV = self.selectedVehicle();
        return selecV.tirepressure_vl + '/' + selecV.tirepressure_vr + '/' + selecV.tirepressure_hl + '/' + slecV.tirepressure_hr + 'bar';
    }, self);
};

ko.applyBindings(new pgViewModel());
```

Comment: Ok, i tried this. Error changed to :'TypeError: self.selectedVehicle is not a function' :/

Answer (score 0):

You have type,It should be:

```
 this.selectedVehicle()//not this.selecttedVehicle()
```

Comment: 'TypeError: this.selectedVehicle is not a function' this is the exact error displyed in the console.